# Helium_python_ig_scrapper

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, helium

I have problem with helium. Because working in 20 minutes and now showing this error anyone help??
error:
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'FirefoxProfile' object has no attribute 'binary'

my code:

```
def chbrowser(browser):
    global ig
    if browser=="f":
        
        fprof = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        fprof.set_preference('intl.accept_languages', 'en-US')
        ig = start_firefox(options=fprof)
    if browser=="ch":
        chopt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chopt.add_argument("--lang=en-US")
        ig = start_chrome(options=chopt)
if __name__=="__main__":
    chbrowser(input("put browser,firefox=f,chrome=ch:
```

"))

Comment: Ah. I have lines sorry for this post

Comment: Please format your code with triple apostrophes.